# import { getArtboardAsJSON } = "xd-json-wrapper" という書き方は正しいですか？

Tags: javascript, node.js

GitHub で公開されている [xd-json-wrapper](https://github.com/svschannak/xd-json-wrapper) の `getArtboardAsJSON` を使いたく、importを行いたいファイル`main.js`で、

**main.js**

```
import { getArtboardAsJSON } = "xd-json-wrapper";//<- この書き方、書く場所は正しいですか？

function myCommand(node) {
     const artboard = node;
     const wrappedArtboard = getArtboardAsJSON(artboard);
     JSON.stringify(wrappedArtboard);
}
```

と書いているのですが、

```
import { getArtboardAsJSON } = "xd-json-wrapper";
```

がSyntaxErrorとして指摘され、読み込めません。

ファイルの階層は以下のようになっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ブラウザはIEですか。IEならimportをサポートされていませんので。　https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility

Comment: main.jsはAdobe XDのプラグインとして使用するファイルで、ブラウザで表示するのものではないです。githubのページではsampleコードにimportが書かれているので使えそうな感じかと思います。

Comment: JavaScript の書式としては正しいもののようです。 - 参考: [import - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) / SyntaxError も省略せずに表示されたメッセージをすべて載せた方が回答のヒントに繋がるかと思います。

Comment: https://github.com/svschannak/xd-json-wrapper/issues/1 / `import hoge = "package"` のような書式はESスタンダードなものではありません。(参考に貼られているMDN内のどれにも一致しないですよね)importをconstのかわりにおくようなシンタックスはTypeScriptにありますが、それもrequireを使うのでちょっとちがう…… / Adobe XDプラグインとしてはnode同様`require()`を用いるようですが…… https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/javascript/javascript-support.html#can-i-use-require

Answer (score 2, accepted):

少なくともそれは、 ESM の `import` 構文としては見たことがありません。当該リポジトリの Issues においても[この構文に関するスレッド](https://github.com/svschannak/xd-json-wrapper/issues)があるので、少なくとも何らかのビルドシステムを通さなければこの構文は使用出来ないのではないかと思います。

その構文の詳細はわかりませんが、当該エラーの解決策は、通常通り `require` 関数を用いてパッケージを読み込むことです。また、 Node.js v12.13.0 では [ESM は実験的 (Stability: 1) な機能](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules)になっており、 xd-json-wrapper パッケージのソースコードを読む限り、 ESM の使用は想定されていないと思われます。

```js
const {getArtboardAsJSON} = require("xd-json-wrapper");

function myCommand(node) {
    const artboard = node;
    const wrappedArtboard = getArtboardAsJSON(artboard);
    JSON.stringify(wrappedArtboard);
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！試してみたいと思います。

Comment: `const { getXDWrapper } = require("./node_modules/xd-json-wrapper/index"); `と書いて読み込めました。

Comment: なるほどそうなのですね。ありがとうございました！